# Align TextView elements alignParentLeft

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, alignment

I want to align many textviews (Contained in each listView item) as `alignParentLeft`, in CSS we use `float:left` and the elements should be blocks (in CSS), here's my xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticketsCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#fff" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CityCountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StartingDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EndingDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticketCategories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the 2 first textviews are well positionned but the others are NOT.

How can I do this ? Thank you.

**EDIT :** this is what I get actually :
[image]

Comment: Starting with the second `TextView` that you want aligned also use the `layout_below` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting this problem because your textview are not aligned to the left - you are getting this problem because you have given all your textview the same attribute - `android:layout_marginTop="25dp"` which means that they will all be the same distance from the top.

To fix this you need to make your textview relative to each other - for example, you `CityCountry` text view should have the attribute `android:layout_below="@id/address"`

That is how a `RelativeLayout` works, because it lets you put elements on top of each other, you have to specify when you don't want them to be on top of each other.

Alternatively you could use a `LinearLayout` with the attribute `android:layout_gravity="right"` and this would stop the textviews from overlapping.